# Decline for-comprehension

Tags: scala, configuration

Has anyone tried to use for-comprehensions with the decline config/command-line library? Using `mapN` with their `Opts` class to produce a config case class gets really unreadable and brittle if it has a lot of members. I'd like to use a for-comprehension instead, something like this:

```
  val databaseConfig: Opts[DatabaseConfig] = {
    for {
      username <- Opts.envWithDefault[String]("POSTGRES_USER", "Postgres username", "postgres")
      password <- Opts.envWithDefault[String]("POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "Postgres password", "postgres")
      hostname <- Opts.envWithDefault[String]("POSTGRES_HOSTNAME", "Postgres hostname", "localhost")
      database <- Opts.envWithDefault[String]("POSTGRES_DATABASE", "Postgres database", "thebean")
      port <- Opts.envWithDefault[Int]("POSTGRES_PORT", "Postgres port", 5432)
      threadPoolSize <- Opts.envWithDefault[Int]("POSTGRES_THREAD_POOL_SIZE", "Postgres thread pool size", 4)
    } yield DatabaseConfig(username, password, hostname, database, port, threadPoolSize)
```

But that seems to be impossible because `Opts` doesn't have `flatMap` defined, and I don't see a good way to implement it (which isn't to say there isn't one). Any suggestions? Did I miss the magical import?

Edit:

The problematic code looks like this (the real problem code has more members, but this gives the idea):

```
(
    Opts.envWithDefault[String]("POSTGRES_USER", "Postgres username", "postgres"),
    Opts.envWithDefault[String]("POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "Postgres password", "postgres"),
    Opts.envWithDefault[String]("POSTGRES_HOSTNAME", "Postgres hostname", "localhost"),
    Opts.envWithDefault[String]("POSTGRES_DATABASE", "Postgres database", "thebean"),
    Opts.envWithDefault[Int]("POSTGRES_PORT", "Postgres port", 5432),
    Opts.envWithDefault[Int]("POSTGRES_THREAD_POOL_SIZE", "Postgres thread pool size", 4)
  ).mapN(DatabaseConfig.apply)
```

If you want to know what environment variable is used to set, say, the port, you have to *count* -- port is the 5th member of the case class, so you have to find the 5th environment variable created in the tuple. That's not great when there are a lot of these.

The following code, suggested in a comment, does improve things:

```
  val username = Opts.envWithDefault[String]("POSTGRES_USER", "Postgres username", "postgres") 
  val password = Opts.envWithDefault[String]("POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "Postgres password", "postgres") 
  val hostname = Opts.envWithDefault[String]("POSTGRES_HOSTNAME", "Postgres hostname", "localhost") 
  val database = Opts.envWithDefault[String]("POSTGRES_DATABASE", "Postgres database", "thebean") 
  val port = Opts.envWithDefault[Int]("POSTGRES_PORT", "Postgres port", 5432)
  val threadPoolSize = Opts.envWithDefault[Int]("POSTGRES_THREAD_POOL_SIZE", "Postgres thread pool size", 4)

  (username, password, hostname, database, port, threadPoolSize).mapN(DatabaseConfig.apply)
```

But isn't this exactly what for-comprehensions are intended for? It seems like using one would be a bit cleaner, so I'm wondering if I'm missing an import or something, or if the library has genuinely decided to make it impossible to flatMap over `Opts`.

Comment: I don't really see the problem. Skipping `for`/`yield`, replacing `<-` by `=`, and then instead of `DatabaseConfig(x,y,z)` writing `(x,y,z).mapN(DatabaseConfig.apply)` would be just as long as your proposed `for-yield`. Could you attach the "unreadable and brittle" code that you're trying to optimize? I.e. "what's the point in using `<-` when `=` would do?"

Comment: I added some more detail. I agree that capturing the various `Opts` objects in variables and then `mapN`ing them into the case class is a viable option. This is just exactly what for-comprehensions are intended for, so it's odd that I'm finding the library made it impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I'm wondering [...]  if the library has genuinely decided to make it impossible to `flatMap` over Opts.

Yes, they have deliberately decided to avoid `flatMap`, because there should be no causal relation between the arguments passed to the earlier options and option-specifications that come after them. For example, allowing something like

```
for
  username <- Opts.envWithDefault[String]("X", "Postgres username", "W") 
  password <- Opts.envWithDefault[String]("Y", s"Password of ${username}", "Z") 
yield SomeConfig(username, password)
```

would result in the absurd conclusion that one needs to know the `username` before one can display help for `password`, because `password`s description depends on the validated `username` argument. This is how the `IO`-monad can behave in an interactive dialogue, but it's unsuitable for `Opts`.

It's intentionally made applicative, and not monadic. Therefore, there is no `flatMap`, and it would be very strange if they attempted to force it into the monadic interface, which is unnecessarily restrictive for this use case.

So, instead of

```
for 
  x <- m1
  y <- m2
  z <- m3
yield Foo(x, y, z)
```

for monadic `m`s just use

```
val x = a1
val y = a2
val z = a3
(a1, a2, a3).mapN(Foo.apply)
```

for applicative `a`s.

Comment: Thanks! My team uses for-comprehensions for EVERYTHING, this was a good reminder that they're not just convenient syntax, they're meant to be used when there's a causal relationship between the items.

Comment: @csjacobs24 Yes, more generally: this is a typical example of an `Applicative` functor. Sometimes, it is advantageous to have less flexible, more rigid, and more "inspectable" notions of computation, where one can predict & precompute more information _about_ a computation ahead of time. For example, applicative parser generators can be used to formulate grammars in such a way that allows computing certain properties of grammars that would not be possible to compute for monadic parser combinators. All kinds of `Validation`-like functors are also very frequently occurring examples.

Comment: This particular example here is kind-of a mix of both: it's something like a little parser, and it's also validating the input, similar to `Validated`.